# Надеть — снять, войти — выйти, нарядить — ?

Tags: антонимы

Новогодние праздники закончились, все убирают елки. Я в шутку говорю, что надо "разрядить" елку. Но а действительно, какой антоним у слова "нарядить"? Почему у слова "зарядить" есть противоположность — "разрядить", а у "нарядить" нету?

Comment: "Раздеть" не годится?

Comment: Мне кажется, что "раздеть" не обязательно относится к наряду.

Comment: **Ну, вот нету и все! Не образовался!**

Comment: Кстати говоря, глаголов с двумя приставками противоположного значения можно найти предостаточно.
Укрупнить - разукрупнить,
уверить - разуверить,
убедить - разубедить.
В последнем примере приставка у- давно слилась с корнем. Эта тема довольно интересна для исследования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Антоним есть: отрядить. Но он частичный и в данном значении не употребляется. 
Виноватить тут надо отсутствие подходящей антонимичной к "на-" приставки . Смотрите, лишь единичные глаголы с приставкой "на-" имеют однокоренные антонимы: налить - отлить, набить - отбить и т.д., причем все такие антонимы - частичные. 
Подобрать же неоднокоренной антоним удаётся далеко не всегда - для этого должен существовать глагол противоположного действия.

Comment: Кх, кх... Где же вы, извиняюсь, видите (кота) приставку? *Наряд* и **ряд** в современном языке не имеют ничего общего. Тем более **отрядить**: если военное "назначать в наряд", так это синоним к "нарядить", а вовсе не антоним - ни частичный, ни полный; а к нарядам, наряжанию **отрядить** отношения никак не имеет.

Answer (score 6):

Глагол 'нарядить' связан смыслом с существительным 'наряд'. Праздничный наряд. Нарядить на праздник кого или что - облечь в роскошный, богатый наряд. Противоположное действие - **разнарядить**, то есть снять наряд. Глагол 'разнарядить' активно употребляется народом именно в значении - снять игрушки с елочки. Пример : "" Вот и дошли наконец руки, чтобы
разнарядить и убрать елку...
Хотя уже было появилась мысль
оставить ее до следующего Нового
Года...""
Нашел рассказ "Мой добрый старый дед мороз" :
 " И моя повзрослевшая дочь, ежегодно
подвешивая по европейской традиции
для сюрпризов свой самодельный
сапожок, в первую очередь ищет
подарок за твоей спиной. И даже наш
кот, пытающийся каждый раз
разнарядить елку и разбросать твою
свиту, почтительно относится к тебе.""
http://marktreview.net/2008/moi-dobryi-staryi-ded-moroz

Comment: Вы много знаете в русском глаголов подобного типа - с двумя приставками противоположного смысла?!

Comment: Слово с двумя приставками *раз* и *на*: **разнарядка**

Answer (score 2):

Мы елку обычно "наряжаем", а потом "убираем" (снимаем, убираем игрушки в коробки и складываем саму елку в коробку). "Разрядить"- тоже иногда используем в узком семейном кругу :)

Comment: Мы говорим "разобрать елку".

Answer (score 0):

Антонимом и будет слово **разрядить**, т.к.

> Образовано из на- + ряд от праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. рядъ, ст.-слав. рѩдъ (др.-греч. τάξις, διαδοχή); русск. ряд, укр. ряд, болг. ред(ъ́т) «ряд, порядок, строка», сербохорв. ре̑д «ряд», словенск. rȇd (род. п. -а) «порядок, ряд, ярус», чешск. řád «порядок, класс (бот.); строй»

*Википедия*

А приставка **раз-**, как уже было сказано, противоположна по смыслу **на-**.

Comment: Противоположность нарядному ребёнку — разрядный?

Comment: По-моему, неуместно приводить "нарядный" как слово, аналогичное данному, т.к. "нарядный" - прилагательное, произошедшее уже от слова "наряд".

Comment: «раз-, как уже было сказано, противоположна по смыслу на-» ============ Кем сказано? Да и кем доказано?

Comment: Сказано: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/15554/18665 (судя по голосам, человек знающий); вот это нашёл прямо сейчас: Приставка на- употребляется при образовании:

1. Существительных со значением: нахождение на поверхности (настенный, нагрудный).

2. Глаголов и обозначает:
а) направленность действия на поверхность извне (наклеить);
б) направленность внутрь (налить); 
в) действие в большом количестве (наварить);
г) доведение действия до естественного предела (намусорить);
д) доведение действия до естественного предела (намусорить);
д) доведение действия до нужного предела (написать).

Comment: Источник: http://project.karelia.ru/atlant/help/prist_ref.htm

Comment: Как видно, нет универсальной формулировки смысла приставки на, поэтому, по-моему, смысл на зависит от самого слова, а следовательно и противоположная приставка.